# Why are there BMX off road races

Tags: bmx, off-road, racing

I was always curious about this, but I never found the answer. Originally I only knew freestyle BMX bikes, but then found there are official races offroad. What is the idea behind this? Sounds like racing giro d'italia on downhill MTB.

Comment: How hard did you look?   That is the origin of BMX.

Comment: Why do a lot of unintuitive sports exist? Because enough people thought it was a fun/good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[BMX was originally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMX) (and still is) run on smooth dirt track that have obstacles such as jumps and whoops (also know as the rhythm sections).   Because the tracks are smooth a small fully rigid bike works amazingly well when ridden appropriately. The BMX bike and track evolved together emphasizing a riding style that is about timing and body position. All of this took off in around the mid-70's just as Mountain biking was in its infancy [with the Repack rides](http://bikinghistory.com/timeline).  The end result is that BMX bikes are really the optimal form factor for BMX tracks.

For example, whoops are a [series of smooth small mounds](http://s27.photobucket.com/user/harpcab/media/Mountain%20Biking%20Pics/Orange%20Y/InTheWhoops.jpg.html) that are typically part of a track's rhythm section.  By  pulling back and up on the bike as you approach the crest and pushing down on the downside you can actually gain speed through this section without pedalling.  If you can continue pedalling while doing so you can gain even more speed.  Some advanced riders may even jump some or all  the whoops, others may manual or wheely through.   The commonality, is controlling your center of gravity so that you body position changes as little as possible while moving the bike over the terrain.

Similarly jumps have smooth lead ups and transitions.  Learning body position, timing and  pumping are some of the techniques used to ensure you land smoothly on the transitions on the backside of each jump.  Good riders will look like they never stop pedalling from when they leave to when they land on the transition.  Advanced riders also do some other pretty impressive things such as rear wheel dabs mid-flight to help control their flight paths and where they will land.

Speed and smoothness is the goal in BMX dirt track racing.  Because the tracks are so controlled, once the various skills are learnt a small rigid bike like a BMX bike is literally the fastest way around the track.

Starting in the 90's many BMX clubs started introducing MTB bike categories to encourage cross-overs. Having ridden both on the tracks, the smaller BMX bikes are faster. Things such as suspension are not needed.  The tracks are smooth and jumps are landed on the transitions (hopefully!).  Suspension just ends up just adding  weight, and can interfere with techniques such as pumping the bike.

Comment: Suspension does more than add weight, it absorbs kinetic energy.

Comment: @ChrisH - agreed, that is why I said suspension can interfere with techniques such as pumping the bike.

Answer (score 3):

More than existing, BMX off road racing is actually an Olympic sport.

According to [Olympic site](http://www.olympic.org/cycling-bmx-equipment-and-history) on this sport:

> Bicycle motocross (BMX) started in the late 1960s in California, around the time that motocross became a popular sport in the USA. The motorised version of the sport was the inspiration for the human-powered competition.

And had an international federation created in 1981:

> In April 1981, the International BMX Federation was founded. BMX rapidly developed a unique sporting identity and it became evident that the sport had more in common with cycling than motorcycling. This was officially recognised in 1993 when BMX was fully integrated into the International Cycling Union (UCI). The sport made its Olympic debut at the 2008 Beijing Games.

Comment: But why would a BMX be used for this, instead of a hardtail/ full suspension ? Does the BMX frame provide something that a standard MTB doesn't ? Or is it just for the lolz ? :P

Comment: It is hard to answer, but according to Wikipedia it began when "young cyclists appropriated motocross tracks for fun, racing and stunts, eventually evolving specialized BMX bikes and competitions". So I guess they had BMX's already and just took them to motocross tracks, as you say, for the lols :) Never underestimate the lolz, think that they created a lot of sports, mainly the most extreme ones :)

Comment: Partially the same reason they use cyclocross frames for cyclocross races.  That's the way it's always been in that sport.  BMX has been around longer than suspension in any usable race form.

Comment: The key you're missing, is that BMX bikes were originally for BMX racing. The tricks didn't come until much later.

Comment: @Giannis  - The BMX (dirt track) form factor was around long before mountain biking and suspension.  By the time MTB came around BMX bikes and categories (i.e., wheel size) were highly standardized.  Tracks were also highly tailored to the BMX bikes by this point too.  Starting in the 90's many BMX clubs even introduced MTB bike categories to encourage cross-overs.  That said, on a BMX dirt track a BMX bike is faster.  Smaller BMX bikes are easier to manual and pump the whoops. Suspension is not needed either as the tracks are smooth and jumps are landed on the transitions (hopefully!).

Comment: Don't forget that general public adherence and sport marketing also play a big part, and that is why old modalities disappear and new ones surface. It's not only a question of: this is the best vehicle for this type of track.